# Convert text URL in a DataTable into an active hyperlink

Tags: r, shiny

[Here is the image of my shiny app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVtwq.png)I have shiny app created using r shiny package with a data table inserted in it from google sheets which has a column of youtube links in it I want to make it as hyperlink so that user can navigate to youtube video of the respective URL

Here is complete code for an app with a table that has links.

## server.r

```
function(input,output,session) {
admin_emails <- c("*************","*************")

addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")

a <- 0
b <- 0
c <- 0
insChart_data <- NULL
ginsChart_data <- NULL
qginsChart_data <- NULL

values <- reactiveValues(authenticated = FALSE, df = 
NULL,gdf=NULL,insChart1_data = 
NULL,ginsChart1_data=NULL,insChart2_data = NULL,ginsChart2_data = 
NULL)
values[['qgdata']] <- gs_merged %>% gs_read(ws="glanceyt") %>% 
as.data.frame() %>% mutate(publishdate = as.Date(publishdate),Week = 
as.Date(publishdate,"%m/%d/%Y"))
```

I have created the table from google sheets, I want the link column to be hyperlinked

Comment: Please include the full code for the app including the server and ui functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HTML link tag and escape html in the data table,

```
links <- c(as.character(tags$a(href = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ",target = "_blank","Link")),
                      as.character(tags$a(href = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ",target = "_blank","Link2")))

data <- data.frame(links = links)


DT::datatable(data.frame(links = links),escape = FALSE)
```

Comment: the datatable call will go in renderDataTable, in the server side.